# Generate HTML with Arrays

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [paths] => /images/100.jpeg
        [title] => Lips
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [paths] => /images/103.jpeg
        [title] => Ball
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [paths] => /images/104.jpeg
        [title] => Sun
    )

)
```

My goal is to take that data and have php loop through and create as many image tags as there are arrays while inserting the data like so:

```
<img src="/images/100.jpeg" title="Lips">
<img src="/images/103.jpeg" title="Ball">
<img src="/images/104.jpeg" title="Sun">
```

...and I am quite lost as to what to do next.

Thank you kindly for your help! It's much appreciated!!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Have you bothered to read any PHP textbooks or tutorials? I expect this type of thing is in hundreds of examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read about `foreach` loops ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php))

Your code will look something like this:

```
foreach($row as $img) {
    echo '<img src="'.$img['paths'].'" alt="'.$img['title'].'">';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo '<img src="'.$value['paths'].'" alt="'.$value['title'].'">';
)
```

Comment: Why do you need the *$key* for? IMHO in this case it's easier to just ```foreach ($array as $value)```

Comment: i don't need it, but someone have to learn how to use foreach, so i show this feature too

Answer (score 1):

You could also do that with an array_walk and implode statement:

```
implode("\n", array_walk($array, function($val, $key) {
  return '<img src="'.$val['paths'].'" alt="'.$val['title'].'">';
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $el) {
    echo "<img src='{$el['paths']}' title='{$el['title']}'>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array=[['paths'=>'/images/100.jpeg', 'titles'=> 'Lips']]

foreach ($array as $row) echo "<img src='".addslashes($row['paths'])."' title='".addslashes($row['titles']."' alt='".addslashes($row['titles']."'/>":
?>
```